# Component is detached while registration of scope-based event listener is in progress

Tags: angularjs, dart, angular-dart

```html
<form>
    ...
    <button ng-click...>Save</button>
</form>
<overlay ng-if="saving" style="background-color: #ff0000">
    <pindicator size="2em" color="red"></pindicator>
</overlay>
```

```dart
void handleOnSaveClicked(final html.Event e) {
    _logger.info("Ready to save:",_tempJob);

    saving = true;

    // Angular starts to register Listener

    _proxy.save(tempJob).then((_) {
        // Template/Component has already received "detach" 

        _logger.info("Job saved!");
        editable = false;
        saving = false;
    });        
}
...
void detach() {
    _logger.info("Detached!");
}
```

proxy.save saves tempJob into a list, this list is observed by Angular.
If this list changes Angular updates all the UI-Elements attached to the list.

saving=true should show a message but if proxy.save is so fast that Angular has no chance to register a Listener for "saving" (https://github.com/angular/angular.dart/blob/master/lib/core/scope.dart - Line 352). the whole UI-Block is remove while Angular tries to register the Listener.

This leads to

```
JobEdit: (15:19:43.096) Ready to save:
JobEdit: (15:19:43.119) Job saved!
JobEdit: (15:19:43.123) Detached!
'package:angular/core/scope.dart': Failed assertion: line 352 pos 12: 'isAttached' is not true.
```

Any hints to avoid this kind of "race condition"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tried it but I think to remember that you should use `VMTurnZone` to execute async operations that affect the model.

```dart
class YourComponent implements ScopeAware {

  Scope scope;
  VmTurnZone zone;

  YourComponent(this.zone);

  void handleOnSaveClicked(final html.Event e) {
    _logger.info("Ready to save:",_tempJob);

    saving = true;

    // Angular starts to register Listener

    zone.run(() {
      return _proxy.save(tempJob).then((_) {
        // Template/Component has already received "detach" 

        _logger.info("Job saved!");
        editable = false;
        saving = false;
      });        
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Cool, Günter Thanks! This brought the solution (at least I hope, as said - its a timing problem) but leads to another problem. "save" updates a list with Jobs (Jobs are complex objects in this case.) The Job-List is my main-list in this App. This: jobs[index] = job; leads to "NotFoundError: The node before which the new node is to be inserted is not a child of this node. Stacktrace: ...#3      domInsert (package:angular/core_dom/dom_util.dart:25:25). There must be a save way to replace objects in Angular-Handled-Lists? I've already tried to wrap this into zone.run - same result.

Comment: I just saw I forgot to add a `return` which is very probably necessary (before `_proxy.save`. The code you posted doesn't show where you call `jobs[index] = job`. Maybe you need to add a callback that is called when `_proxy.save` is done (Just a wild guess because I don't know what you actually try to accomplish).

Comment: return was not necessary. run returns what the calling function returns - so in this case it would be a Future. "then" is already the callback you recommend. Proxy.save saves the Job on the server, if the server comes back with 200 the Job is updated in the local Job-List. (jobs[index] = job;) Update means here replace one object with another - I alway get "detach" before I get Angulars/Dart Error-Message. Angular tries to insert (Node.insertBefore) something into DOM that produces the "NotFoundError". The funny thing is also that it works with jobs[0] = job; (first in list)

Comment: If added a new question for the "replace" problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26523654/replacing-an-item-in-list-causes-notfounderror-in-angulardart

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is replacing the list item with a new instance of your class (new object)

Angular tests the objects hashCode if you replace a list item.
If the hashCode is different it deletes the according component, but if the hashCode is the same
it updates the vars in your html-file.

Here it also deletes the component and replaces it with the new device:

```
...
// hashCode of devices[42] changes
devices[42] = new Device(new Location(40.123,10.567));
```

But this **updates!** your component:

```
...
// hashCode of devices[42] stays the same

final Device device = devices[42]; 
device.location = new Location(40.123,10.567);
```