# Replacing an item in List causes NotFoundError in AngularDart

Tags: dart, angular-dart

"replace" is called if I click on `<a class="replace" href="#" ng-click="replace(musician.lastname)">[ REPL ]</a>`

```dart
void replace(final String lastname) {
    _zone.run(() {

        final Address addressFromList = _model.musicians.firstWhere((final Address address) => lastname == address.lastname);
        final int index = _model.musicians.indexOf(addressFromList);

        _logger.info("Replace $lastname (Index: $index)");
        _model.musicians[index] = new Address("Tina","Turner");
    });
}
```

if index is 0 (first one) it works but fails with all others:

```
NotFoundError: The node before which the new node is to be inserted is not a child of this node.

STACKTRACE:
#0      BlinkNode.insertBefore_Callback_Node_Node (dart:_blink:270)
#1      Node.insertBefore (dart:html:23205)
#2      Node.insertAllBefore (dart:html:22868)
#3      domInsert (package:angular/core_dom/dom_util.dart:25:25)
#4      Animate.insert (package:angular/core_dom/animation.dart:44:19)
#5      ViewPort.insert.<anonymous closure> (package:angular/core_dom/view.dart:75:22)
...
```

GH: http://goo.gl/kOeAkc (replace function)
GH: http://goo.gl/4FfYlo (AppController)

Here is the JS Version: http://www.mikemitterer.at/fileadmin/sourcesamples/accordion/ (Same result)

In my sample, if you replace "Mozart" with "Tina Turner" it works but if you replace "Mercury" with TT it fails...

Comment: I have heard that `Mercury` doesn't like to be replaced :-P .  Seriously, I think this is an Angular bug. As a workaround you could try to replace the list instead of modifying it like `_model.musicians = _model.musicians.toList()..[index] = new Address("Tina","Turner");`